# scheduled tasks running but have disappeared

Tags: shutdown, scheduled, task-management

I had recently installed gnome-schedule 2.1.1-4 onto my ubuntu 12.10 so that i may be able to schedule a recurrent shutdown on my laptop everyday at 1:55 pm.

After a few days when i didn't need the scheduled shutdown task any more so i wished to remove it.

Even though it still shuts down at 1:55 pm but the task isn't visible in the task  schedule window on gnome-schedule 2.1.1-4.

how do i remove this task?

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution, just open your terminal, and type 
"sudo gnome-schedule" I guess your scheduled task will appear :)